# Kernel doesn't play well with USB ports

Tags: boot, usb, kernel, mouse

I am using Kubuntu 22.04 LTS on an ASUS Vivobook and i have been experiencing problems with my USB ports.

I tried plugging in my mouse into my computer (on all USB ports) but it wouldn't work. Upon a reboot, i noticed that my mouse would work, but once i logged in it would stop getting power (the mouse sensor would stop). This was on kernel version linux-5.15.0-33-generic.

Running `sudo dmesg | grep usb` would show similar output:

```
[   41.505224] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[   41.506124] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[   41.506129] usb 3-2.1: USB disconnect, device number 4
[   41.509860] usb 3-2.2: USB disconnect, device number 5
```

Needless to say, other commands, such as lsusb wouldn't show the ports or devices.

I tried 5.15.0-30-generic. My USB devices worked again... until the next reboot. I have also tested 5.17.11-051711-generic and 5.10.118-0510118-generic but to no avail.

Out of desperation, i rebooted (once more) and have discovered that my mouse worked *until* i used my laptop keyboard, so it would seem to me that the keyboard... steals power (?) from the USB ports.

I'm not expecting so much of a solution as i wanted to post to issue somewhere in hopes that if it happens to somebody else they would be able to find a solution here. Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Have you tried to connect your USB devices via a hub with its own power supply (directly from the power grid)?

Comment: Don't have one of those and neither do i think i can borrow one :P

Comment: A  hub with its own power supply would give a chance to test the theory about lack for power from the USB ports. But I am not sure that is your problem. Have you tested with another operating system, for example a ***live*** (booted from USB) Kubuntu or some other version (not 22.04 LTS) or even some other Linux distro? That would help finding out, if you have a software problem or a hardware problem. Is some other device connected to USB, not mentioned in the original question?

Comment: Okay so i played around and i found out that USB devices don't work unless the laptop is charging. So there's that...

Comment: Please put the answer as an answer and not in the question. and then mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was tlp. For those who don't know, tlp is a piece of software that helps with reducing battery usage. Apparently, one of the neat things tlp does in that regard is cut power from USB ports. If it affects you, just stick to [auto-cpufreq](https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/auto-cpufreq).

Comment: TLP doesn't cut power to USB ports. Your symptoms are more likely due to a malfunction of the kernel power management. Check the [FAQ for workarounds](https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/usb.html#newly-inserted-usb-devices-not-recognized-in-battery-mode).

Comment: This solved my issue. I disabled tlp and it solved. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1480412/usb-keyboard-and-mouse-dont-work-after-upgrade-to-22-04